# amavisd-new rescans quarantined mails

Tags: ubuntu, amavis, opensmtpd

iam using Opensmtpd on a 14.04.4 LTS Ubuntu with amavisd-new as Mailscanner.
We configured the quarantine so it sends the Virus-Mails to an external mailbox. This works fine until the point amavis has found a virus/spam Mail - it gets sent to our quarantine mailbox but the mail is getting scanned again and again - means that if it was postive scanned the mail-admin is informed and after that the mail redirected to our quarantine mailbox - and here it is scanned again which produces a warning again - and a new scan - and a new warning and so on.

I tried to whitelist our postmaster at amavis but the virus/spam mails are originated somewhere else and thus scanned again.
Anyone with an idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I guess i found it out:

Whitelisting Virus and Spam Recipients works with the following configuration for amavisd-new:

```
@bypass_spam_checks_acl = qw( quarantine@123.de quarantine@456.com );
@bypass_virus_checks_acl = qw( quarantine@123.de quarantine@456.com );
```

if the following is set:

```
@bypass_virus_checks_maps = (
 \%bypass_virus_checks, \@bypass_virus_checks_acl, \$bypass_virus_checks_re);
```

Important part: **\@bypass_virus_checks_acl**

and

```
@bypass_spam_checks_maps = (
\%bypass_spam_checks, \@bypass_spam_checks_acl, \$bypass_spam_checks_re);
```

Important part: **\@bypass_spam_checks_acl**